# Can't connect to XMPP server (openfire) with HTTP binding

Tags: xmpp, strophe

I'm trying to learn XMPP protocol to make web applications using it.

So, I've installed a XMPP daemon called openfire, I configured it to support HTTP-Bind, I can connect to it using Pidgin and the default XMPP protocol.

The problem is that I can't connect to it using HTTP-Binding. In pidgin I have some options when I'm connecting to specify method whici I want to use to connect to server. If I set it to connect using HTTP-Bind it fails with this message: No session id given.

At the client side, I'd use Strophejs try to make this connection, but it doesn't work too. I have something like this:

```
var conn = new Strophe.Connection("http://chat.dev/http-bind");
```

Where http://chat.dev/http-bind is the location to the XMPP daemon. I've been forwarded this location to be set on the properly port in apache virtualhost, so the http://chat.dev/http-bind will point to the same thing as http: / / 127.0.0.1:7070.

```
conn.connect("test5", "test5", some_callback);

function some_callback(status)
{
if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTING) {
    console.log('Strophe is connecting.');
} else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL) {
    console.log('Strophe failed to connect.');  
} else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTING) {
    console.log('Strophe is disconnecting.');
} else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
    console.log('Strophe is disconnected.');
} else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
    console.log('Strophe is connected.');
 // connection.disconnect();
}
}
```

This will return: "Strophe is connecting."

Well, I don't know the answer, I've been reading a book about XMPP and Strophe, but this book doesn't cover this aspect and the documentation which I've found also doesn't help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds to me like OpenFire is not correctly configured to use BOSH and  HTTP-binding.

Comment: How can I check if this is true?

Comment: Tell us more about your setup, please. IS your Openfire daemon running on the same host/IP as your web server? On which port do you have your Openfire configured to listen for incoming BOSH connections? Are you loading the Strophe `flxhr` plugin? Are you able to load the Openfire admin interface in your browser by pointing to `http://chat.dev:9090` ?

Comment: I can access chat.dev:9090, I can log-in intro admin panel. I don't use flxhr.

Answer (score 0):

Try this- 
var conn = new Strophe.Connection("http://chat.dev/http-bind/");

Need to put '/' in the end. Worked for me.